# How to translate a variable by JText in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, translation

This code works well:

`print JText::_('HELLO_USER');`

But this does not work:

`$test = "HELLO_USER";
print JText::_($test);`

While my .ini file contains this line:

`HELLO_USER="Hello dear user!";`

How can I make it works!?? I'm not gonna pass "HELLO_USER" directly to JText.

Comment: check the path of language **ini** file in your extension. For more information read here - https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_language_management

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a more complete explanation:
https://docs.joomla.org/Formatted_fields_in_language_translation_strings